# Run the CommandTFlush command when a new file is written

Tags: function, vim, autocmd

I'm trying to make Vim run the command 'CommandTFlush' whenever a new file is writte. For those not using the Command-T plugin, the 'CommandTFlush' command is used to rebuild an index of files in the current directory.

What I want to do is run the command after the file is written to disk, so that CommandTFlush will find the file and add it to it's index.

I've tried writing a function myself, but either it doesn't fire or it fires too soon (before the file is written, and the whole point is to add the file to the index):

```
au! BufWritePre * ks| call NewFilesUpdatesCommandT()
function! NewFilesUpdatesCommandT()
    let filename=@%
    if !filereadable(filename)
        CommandTFlush
    endif
endfunction
```

I suspect it could be solved by setting some boolean var (isTheFileNew) in BufWritePre and then execute the CommandTFlush command in BufWritePost if the file was just created, but I can't figure out the syntax. Another solution could be setting/unsetting the BufWritePost callback from within BufWritePre callback, if that's possible...

Could anybody help me out here? ;)

Comment: What `ks|` at the start of your autocommand is doing? Cannot find it in vim help.

Comment: Found it. Why do you want to mark your position if your function does not move the cursor?

Comment: No idea really. It's just a bad copy/paste job based on some pointers I got in #vim@freenode.net. Haven't quite figured out how to get something helpful out of the help files yet. I'm on my third day with Vim here ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
augroup NFUCT
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePre * call NFUCTset()
augroup END
function NFUCTset()
    if !filereadable(expand('%'))
        augroup NFUCT
            autocmd BufWritePost * call NFUCT()
        augroup END
    endif
endfunction
function NFUCT()
    augroup NFUCT
        autocmd!
        autocmd BufWritePre * call NFUCTset()
    augroup END
    CommandTFlush
endfunction
```

This is a realization of your second suggestion.

Answer (score 17):

Here is my solution. It triggers CommandTFlush whenever a file is written and also whenever Vim's window gains focus. This is useful when you create files outside of vim - for example by switching between branches in your version control system. The new files will be available in CommandT immediately after you re-enter Vim.

```
augroup CommandTExtension
  autocmd!
  autocmd FocusGained * CommandTFlush
  autocmd BufWritePost * CommandTFlush
augroup END
```

Comment: That works very well. I just stuck that in my .vimrc and now CommandT works as I'd expect it to. Thanks.